# How to divide paper up into smaller pages in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, page, cards

I need to create some cards, of various sizes, cut from larger letter (8.5" x 11") pages. These are for putting in different sized pocket charts for displaying information in a classroom.

All are fairly simple, with header (just like on regular pages) plus some large, vertically and horizontally centered text. Here are some sample layouts:

These cards measure 8.5" x 5:

```
 _____________________
| Header              |
|                     | <--page 1
|    Centered text    |
|                     |
|---------------------|
| Header              |
|                     | <--page 2, but would be printed on same paper
|    Centered text    |
|                     |
|_____________________|
```

These cards measure 11"x4" in landscape mode and the bottom 0.5" is discarded:

```
 __________________________
| Header                   |
|       Centered text      |
|--------------------------|
| Header                   |
|       Centered text      |
|--------------------------|
|__________________________|
```

Is there a way to have ConTeXt setup the pages this way? A simple `\pagebreak` command would send documents to the next "page" while still being on the same physical page when printed, and headers appear on top like normal. Cuttings lines aren't needed, as I can measure on a paper cutter to get the cuts right.

Comment: https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use ConTeXt's [imposition](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition) mechanism.  The examples have to be typeset using `context --arrange`.

```
\setuparranging[2TOP]

\definepapersize
    [card]
    [height=5in,width=8.5in]

\setuppapersize
    [card]
    [letter]

\definemakeup
    [custom]
    [align=middle,headerstate=start]

\setupheadertexts[Header][]

\showframe

\starttext

\startmakeup[custom]
    Centered text
\stopmakeup

\startmakeup[custom]
    Centered text
\stopmakeup

\stoptext
```

[image]

For the second layout just replace in the above

```
\definepapersize
    [card]
    [height=4in,width=11in]

\setuppapersize
    [card]
    [letter,landscape]
```

[image]